# Как перейти на сайт без URL?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Как сделать так, чтобы драйвер перешёл на другой сайт вместе с нажатием по элементу? Просто URL ка каждом аккаунте разный. Пример:

```
Brouser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://vk.com/feed");
IWebElement mYSTR = Brouser.FindElement(By.LinkText("Моя Cторінка"));
mYSTR.Click();
IWebElement Myname = Brouser.FindElement(By.ClassName("page_name"));
// тут ошибка, потому что драйвер остался на https://vk.com/feed
```

Comment: не понятно ничего, где URL меняется? что значит "в месте с нажатиям по элементу"?

Comment: Так понятней?))

Comment: А, может, после клика нужно дождаться загрузки страницы? И в последней строке, видимо, стоит написать `IWebElement` вместо `IWebElemen` и `By` вместо `B`.

Comment: сделать таймер, после нажатия команды mYSTR.Click(); ?

Comment: Какой именно драйвер используете? Chrome, Firefox, другой? 
Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Также в коде очень много описок: `IWebElemen Myname`, а нужно `IWebElement Myname` и `Brouser.FindElement(By.ClassName("page_name"));`. И последнее: рекомендую пользоваться для поиска элемента страницы By.XPath. Почитайте про него, т.к. когда вы ищете элемент по тексту ссылки, то, во-первых, тест не сработает для регионов с другим языком, а также разработчики сайта могут поменять текст ссылки на совершенно другой, поэтому данная привязка крайне нежелательна.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае то, что URL изменяется, не имеет никакого значения. Дело в том, что Ваш тест, вероятнее всего, завершается быстрее, чем открывается новая страница по нажатию кнопки. Поэтому необходимо создать ожидание для данного события нажатия по веб-элементу.

Код может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
    Brouser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://vk.com/feed");
    IWebElement mYSTR = Brouser.FindElement(By.LinkText("Моя Cторінка"));
    mYSTR.Click();

    // Создаем локатор для элементов, которые должны быть видимы при следующем действии
    By nextPageMainElementsLocator = By.ClassName("page_name"); // Здесь лучше 
              //поместить другой локатор. Но т.к. я не знаю, какая именно страница открывается, то лучше и не предложишь

    // Создаем ожидание
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12.00));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(nextPageMainElementsLocator));

    // Все, теперь мы точно знаем, что элементы, локатором для которых является nextPageMainElementsLocator, видимы.
    IWebElement Myname = Brouser.FindElement(By.ClassName("page_name"));
```

В заключение хочу порекомендовать Вам почитать про правильное написание локаторов. Также рекомендую посмотреть в сторону локаторов XPath.